# Count jBoss AS7 session by code

Tags: java, jboss, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, jboss7.x

I'm developing a Web Application with Seam in jBoss AS7 on Amazon Web Services infrastructure. I have implemented the automatism to scale up the infrastructure but I need to learn two things about AS7 configuration:

1) How to configure AS7 to share the user session on different Server? I need to configure a Cluster like this link
https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/AS7+Cluster+Howto

2) Is there a way to count the open sessions in single AS7 by code?
I need to create an automatic down-scaling of the AWS infrastructure to switch-off EC2 machine without interrupt the user work.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use an HttpSessionListener and increment a counter in an external database on sessionCreated and decrement from the same database on sessionDestroyed.

```
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSessionEvent;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSessionListener;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

public class SessionCounter implements HttpSessionListener {

    public SessionCounter() {
    }

    public void sessionCreated(HttpSessionEvent event) {
        //@TODO increment database value
    }

    public void sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent event) {
        //@TODO decrement database value
    }

    public int getActiveSessionNumber() {
        //@TODO return database value
    }
}
```